# odbc connect to hive error in Rstudio-Server "SASL(-4): no mechanism available: No worthy mechs found" but works fine in terminal

Tags: r, hive, odbc, rstudio, rstudio-server

I'm trying to upgrade Rstudio Server from 1.2.5042 to the newest, 2021.09.1-372. But something is wrong when I try to connect with hive via odbc. Then I downgrade Rstudio Server to 1.4.1106, the error is the same.

[image]

[image]

```r
> library(DBI)
> con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "hive", timeout = 10)
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [Cloudera][ThriftExtension] (9) Error occurred while authenticating via SASL. Error details: SASL(-4): no mechanism available: No worthy mechs found
```

But when I go back to 1.2.5042, odbc works fine. I compared `Sys.getenv()` results from Rstudio console and Rstudio terminal, there's nothing diffrent about LD_LIBRARY_PATH or PATH. I googled and found others with the same error. But they are using python or something else, and they fixed it by `apt install libsasl2 libsasl2-dev` or something else. But since odbc works fine in terminal both inside rstudio and outside rstudio, and in rstudio 1.2.5042, odbc env of my machine is already correct. And also, `isql -v hive` works fine. (DSN hive is already set in ~/.odbc.ini). I don't know how to get is work now. I use odbc to query data from hive every day. Is there any settings which should be done in new version of Rstudio Server ?

Outputs of `Sys.getenv()` and `sessionInfo()` are as followings:

```r
> Sys.getenv()
CLICOLOR_FORCE                          1
CLOUDERAHIVEINI                         /opt/cloudera/hiveodbc/lib/64//cloudera.hiveodbc.ini
DISPLAY                                 :0
EDITOR                                  vi
GIT_ASKPASS                             rpostback-askpass
HOME                                    /home/rstudio
LANG                                    en_US.UTF-8
LD_LIBRARY_PATH                         /usr/local/lib/R/lib::/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/server
LN_S                                    ln -s
LOGNAME                                 rstudio
MAKE                                    make
MPLENGINE                               tkAgg
PAGER                                   /usr/bin/pager
PATH                                    /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin:/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/postback
R_BROWSER                               xdg-open
R_BZIPCMD                               /usr/bin/bzip2
R_DOC_DIR                               /usr/local/lib/R/doc
R_GZIPCMD                               /usr/bin/gzip
R_HOME                                  /usr/local/lib/R
R_INCLUDE_DIR                           /usr/local/lib/R/include
R_LIBS                                  /usr/local/lib/R/site-library:/usr/local/lib/R/library
R_LIBS_SITE                             
R_LIBS_USER                             ~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0
R_PAPERSIZE                             letter
R_PDFVIEWER                             /usr/bin/xdg-open
R_PLATFORM                              x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
R_PRINTCMD                              /usr/bin/lpr
R_RD4PDF                                times,inconsolata,hyper
R_SESSION_TMPDIR                        /tmp/Rtmpdxn0JW
R_SHARE_DIR                             /usr/local/lib/R/share
R_STRIP_SHARED_LIB                      strip --strip-unneeded
R_STRIP_STATIC_LIB                      strip --strip-debug
R_SYSTEM_ABI                            linux,gcc,gxx,gfortran,gfortran
R_TEXI2DVICMD                           /usr/bin/texi2dvi
R_UNZIPCMD                              /usr/bin/unzip
R_ZIPCMD                                /usr/bin/zip
RMARKDOWN_MATHJAX_PATH                  /usr/lib/rstudio-server/resources/mathjax-27
RS_RPOSTBACK_PATH                       /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rpostback
RS_SESSION_TMP_DIR                      /var/run/rstudio-server/rstudio-rsession
RSTUDIO                                 1
RSTUDIO_CONSOLE_COLOR                   256
RSTUDIO_CONSOLE_WIDTH                   135
RSTUDIO_HTTP_REFERER                    http://10.27.5.209:8789/
RSTUDIO_PANDOC                          /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/pandoc
RSTUDIO_PROGRAM_MODE                    server
RSTUDIO_R_MODULE                        
RSTUDIO_R_PRELAUNCH_SCRIPT              
RSTUDIO_R_REPO                          
RSTUDIO_R_VERSION_LABEL                 
RSTUDIO_SESSION_STREAM                  rstudio-d
RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY                   rstudio
RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY_DISPLAY           rstudio
RSTUDIO_WINUTILS                        bin/winutils
SED                                     /usr/bin/sed
SSH_ASKPASS                             rpostback-askpass
TAR                                     /usr/bin/tar
TERM                                    xterm-256color
USER                                    rstudio
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.8.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C              LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] DBI_1.1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bit_4.0.4       odbc_1.3.1      compiler_4.0.4  ellipsis_0.3.1  hms_1.0.0       tools_4.0.4     Rcpp_1.0.6      bit64_4.0.5    
 [9] vctrs_0.3.7     blob_1.2.1      lifecycle_1.0.0 pkgconfig_2.0.3 rlang_0.4.10
```

My `odbc.ini` content is as following. It works in rstudio 1.2.5042.

```
[hive]
Description=Cloudera ODBC Driver for Apache Hive (64-bit)
Driver=/opt/cloudera/hiveodbc/lib/64/libclouderahiveodbc64.so
Host = 192.168.90.54
Port = 10000
UID = hive_username
PWD = hive_password
AuthMech = 3
UseSASL = 1
Database = default
UseNativeQuery=1
```

**For a minimal example**, we can use docker to run a hiveserver2 quickly,  a docker-hive example  can be found here: https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hive. Clone it and cd to its directory and then `docker-compose up -d`  will make a simple hive run. And then add new DSN to `.odbc.ini`, a new connection can be built in rstudio-server pane. Then we can make the error show again.

```
[hive_test]
Description=Cloudera ODBC Driver for Apache Hive (64-bit)
Driver=/opt/cloudera/hiveodbc/lib/64/libclouderahiveodbc64.so
Host = YOUR_LOCAL_IP(or localhost)
Port = 10000
Database = default
UseNativeQuery = 1
```

By the way, I tried Rstudio desktop on Windows and MacOS, connecting to hive both work fine. This error only occurs in Rstudio-Server. I tried to copy env variables from R in terminal to R console in Rstudio-server, nothing changes. I also tried pyodbc via Rstudio-server terminal and recticulate in Rstudio-server console, pyodbc also works fine in terminal but the same error occurs in Rstudio-server terminal.

Update, I tried on Ubuntu, and Rstudio desktop has same error.

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded cloudera odbc driver to version 2.6.11 and the error disappears. It's wierd that it only occurs in Rtudio and both in R and Python, but it works well in terminal. Anyway, new version of driver avoids the error.
Hope my experience would help others.